# What is the intent-filter to advertise to receive text (JSON) from another application?

Tags: android, json, android-intent, intentfilter

The Trainingpeaks app is able to export a JSON representation of a workout.  I downloaded a JSON viewer on Android and it works.  I wish to write my own app to receive this intent and do something with it.  The problem is my app is not recognised as being able to receive this intent.  What form should the intent-filter take?  If I add a data tag to the existing manifest file intent-filter the app does not appear on the device.  If I set up two intent-filters it does but all the combinations of action category and data tags that I have tried do not allow my app to be recognised to receive the JSON.  I am amazed at how poorly documented this is and pretty hacked off at having resort to trial and error.  The last thing I tried was:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: "I am amazed at how poorly documented this is" -- did you ask the developers of the Trainingpeaks app what `Intent` structure they are using? Or, did you examine Logcat to determine what `Intent` structure they are using? It would be nice if the Trainingpeaks developers documented it, but not everybody documents their APIs. Another option is to use an app [like this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo) to examine your JSON viewer's manifest and see what it is using for `<intent-filter>`. For example, it might be `ACTION_VIEW` instead of `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: No.  TPs do not wish to play.  Thanks for the tips though.  I found this line in logcat which I think must be it?   04-20 18:20:51.205  3821  4520 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/json flg=0x1 cmp=null} from uid 10303 .       I don't wish to specify the uid.    What would you suggest for the intent-filter configuration?  Again thanks.  Drew.

Comment: It works.  VIEW and application.json.  I was sure I had already tried that but that may be when I added those lines to the original intent filter which stops the app installing on the device.  I didn't find the official android documentation helpful other than in sketch overview of concepts.  At least it works now so I should be able to get my json from the bundle.  Thanks a lot.  Drew.

Comment: OK.  I now have a single key value pair in the bundle.  It is of type android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.  Its value is content://com.peaksware.trainingpeaks.provider.enteranl_files/TrainingPeaks/2019-04-21.  Is this is a URL to download JSON from their server?  I put in a browser but it just says <uri> did not match any documents.  Why?

Comment: "Is this is a URL to download JSON from their server?" -- no. The `Uri` begins with `content`, not `http` or `https`. That is a `Uri` to a `ContentProvider`, probably a `FileProvider` used by their app. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So the solitary key value pair in the extra bundle returns an instance of type HierarchicalUri.  I got this from .getClass().getClassName() .   The problem is I am unable to declare an object of this type to receive the value from .get(key) as it isn't recognised.  There is no suggested import either.  Is it a real object type?  Where is it defined?  Or is it merely a sort of object type identifier alias for a URI and can I typcast it?

Comment: "So the solitary key value pair in the extra bundle returns an instance called HierarchicalUri" -- for `ACTION_VIEW`, you get the `Uri` to view by calling `getData()` on the `Uri`. That will be an object of type `Uri`.

Comment: That didn't work.  I cast the single value in the extra bundle of type HierarchicalUri to Uri and resolver returned a non-null cursor.  Using .toString() on the cursor returns: "android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@2a98213" which does not help me.  How do I get column names from this cursor?

Comment: "resolver returned a non-null cursor" -- `openInputStream()` does not return a `Cursor`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  An instance of ContentResolver does via .query(args)!  You can even get the data size this way.  It is a bit of a red herring though.  Your comment put me back on track.  Used .openInputstream(uri).  Build the JSON string using .read() with a (char) typecast.  Thanks very much indeed.  As someone once said to me - now we are cooking on gas!  Still not sure what this HierarchicalUri is and any idea why I can cast to a simple Uri and nothing breaks?

Comment: `Uri` is an `abstract` class. `HierarchicalUri` is a concrete subclass of `Uri`, one implemented as a `static` (nested) class of `Uri`. From your app's standpoint, that's an implementation detail that is invisible to you -- you just work with the `Uri` API.